# Jruby 1.6.0.RC2 + Rails3 + Glassfish-gem = big fail

Tags: glassfish, jruby

Having problems getting glassfish to even run on my server.  jRuby is absoutely maddening to begin with, but this is killing me.

I have a pretty complex app, so I won't go into too many details, other than to say the Rails2 version is working under jRuby 1.5.1.

When I start and do the first hit on the server I get the following error:

```
Feb 19, 2011 12:20:14 AM com.sun.grizzly.jruby.RackGrizzlyAdapter dispatchRequest 
WARNING: (NoMethodError) undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass 
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass   
at Rack::Handler::Grizzly.call(/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.0.RC2/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.dev-universal-java/lib/rack/handler/grizzly.rb:55)
```

I have tried starting glassfish every way since sunday and have also swapped out various gems.  It seems bundler 1.0.10 also has some issues. It broke my Rails2 app.

Any insite anywhere as to where to even start looking would be appreciated.

The app works just fine when running webrick.

Comment: Forgot, it works with glassfish on my Mac.  Could be a java or OS thing.  Running Ubuntu 10.10 server.  I am considering rebuilding that as 10.04 but don't want to waste a bunch of time on that for nothing.

Comment: I don't know if the glassfish gem is still maintained, I prefer Torquebox wich is based on JBoss and it's build with JRuby for JRuby.

Comment: Yeah, I found that to be the case.  The problem was another major issue in glassfish too, that there was no fix for.  I am using Trinidad now which is tomcat based.  I will look at TorqueBox too, I have heard good things about it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jRuby stack still has a long way to go.  Finally figured this debacle out.  Turns out the rackup.rb file pulled into glassfish from an as yet unidentified source (I hacked it for now and moved on) has logic that only supports rack in development, test or production.  I was using a multistage environment so I could test things out.  I had a, shocker, staging environment.  So this all worked fine under the old glassfish that detected and ran rails separately but created a host of issues for the rails3 application running with a config.ru rack file.

I will post an update to my blog when I get this nailed down correctly.  You can't monkey patch this because glassfish loads from the installed gem location not your own project or even bundle repository.